# #program in C - How read a word and the line of this word in a .txt? C program

Tags: c

I'm trying write a code using C, where I have a file with more than 300.000 lines. So I want look a specific word (# P5P5) that appear more than 1 time and read the respective lines of this word also. But my program only search the first word and stop... I want do a loop for find the others.

Thanks,
Gabriela

So, my code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
FILE *arquivo = fopen("testando.txt", "r");
char caractere; // caractere a ser lido
int existe_linhas = 0;
int quant_linhas = 0;
int num = 0;

char pesquisa[] = "# 00"; // string a ser pesquisada
int pos = 0; // posicao de início da pesquisa
int encontrei = 0;  // status da pesquisa


if(arquivo != NULL) //verifica se o arq foi aberto ok
{


 while((caractere = fgetc(arquivo)) != EOF)
     {
  // vamos verificar se o caractere atual se iguala ao
  // primeiro caractere da string a ser pesquisada

    existe_linhas = 1; // há conteúdo no arquivo

  if((caractere == pesquisa[0]) && (!encontrei))
    {
    encontrei = 1; // podemos continuar a pesquisa a partir daqui
    pos = 0;
    }

  if(encontrei)
    {
    if(caractere == pesquisa[pos])
      {
      encontrei = 1; // continua a pesquisa
      pos++; // incrementa a posição de busca

      if(pos == strlen(pesquisa))
        break;            
      }
    else{
      encontrei = 0;     
    }              
  }

  if(caractere == '\n') //verificar se é quebra de linha
    {
     quant_linhas++;
    }





    } //fecha o while

  if(existe_linhas)
     quant_linhas++;

    if(encontrei){
        printf("A string pesquisada existe no arquivo");
    }
    else{
        printf("A string pesquisada NAO existe no arquivo");
    }

    printf("\n\n");

printf("A string pesquisada está na linha %d.", quant_linhas);
fclose(arquivo); // libera o ponteiro para o arquivo
}


else
printf("Nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo.");


printf("\n\n");
system("PAUSE");    
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you find the word you use break, which stops the while loop and stops reading characters from the file.

```
if(pos == strlen(pesquisa))
    break;      // this is where you stop the loop instead of doing what you want to do when you find the word.      
  }
```

I didn't really understand what you want to do when you find the word, can you please try to clarify what you aim to do in your code?

As a side note, you don't reset encontrei when you start a newline.

Comment: Hi, 
After I found word I want find the next same word. Because in my .txt I have this word many times. I want know the number of the line where i find this word. For example: line 3, line 200, line 1000, etc. Because this .txt is a data .txt where I have more than 300.000 lines with blocks of data.

Answer (score 2):

As TomerSH said,

In the

```
if(pos == strlen(pesquisa)) break;
```

you are stopping the while loop, instead of that you could increment a variable to count how many times the word appears and reset your pos and encontrei variables to search the next characters in the file.

Comment: Thanks, I will do this, because I saw that i need reset the variables... but i didn't know where....